# Update chromedriver whenever chrome browser updates

Tags: google-chrome, browser, selenium-chromedriver

Is it necessary to update chromedriver (used in automation bot) whenever the Chrome browser updates? Or the bot would run fine with older version of chromedriver and newer version of browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is necessary to update `chromedriver` whenever `chrome` browser updates.
You can find guide to select `chromedriver` version here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

Recently I found that `chromedriver` has almost one-to-one version accordance now (there was three-last-releases support policy for `chromedriver 2.46`).

I've [wrote simple powershell script](https://codeofclimber.ru/2019/getting-chromedriver-updates/) for updating `chromedriver` automatically (on Windows platform).

Run this script when you need to update `crhomedriver` (I run this script as build step in my CI, just before I run selenium web tests):

```bsh
$thisScriptRoot = if ($PSScriptRoot -eq "") { "." } else { $PSScriptRoot }

$chromeDriverRelativeDir = "Selenium"
$chromeDriverDir = $(Join-Path $thisScriptRoot $chromeDriverRelativeDir)
$chromeDriverFileLocation = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver.exe")
$chromeVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").FileVersion
$chromeMajorVersion = $chromeVersion.split(".")[0]

if (-Not (Test-Path $chromeDriverDir -PathType Container)) {
  $dir = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $chromeDriverDir
}

if (Test-Path $chromeDriverFileLocation -PathType Leaf) {
  # get version of curent chromedriver.exe
  $chromeDriverFileVersion = (& $chromeDriverFileLocation --version)
  $chromeDriverFileVersionHasMatch = $chromeDriverFileVersion -match "ChromeDriver (\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)"
  $chromeDriverCurrentVersion = $matches[1]

  if (-Not $chromeDriverFileVersionHasMatch) {
    Exit
  }
}
else {
  # if chromedriver.exe not found, will download it
  $chromeDriverCurrentVersion = ''
}

if ($chromeMajorVersion -lt 73) {
  # for chrome versions < 73 will use chromedriver v2.46 (which supports chrome v71-73)
  $chromeDriverExpectedVersion = "2.46"
  $chromeDriverVersionUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"
}
else {
  $chromeDriverExpectedVersion = $chromeVersion.split(".")[0..2] -join "."
  $chromeDriverVersionUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_" + $chromeDriverExpectedVersion
}

$chromeDriverLatestVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $chromeDriverVersionUrl

Write-Output "chrome version:       $chromeVersion"
Write-Output "chromedriver version: $chromeDriverCurrentVersion"
Write-Output "chromedriver latest:  $chromeDriverLatestVersion"

# will update chromedriver.exe if MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH
$needUpdateChromeDriver = $chromeDriverCurrentVersion -ne $chromeDriverLatestVersion
if ($needUpdateChromeDriver) {
  $chromeDriverZipLink = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + $chromeDriverLatestVersion + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
  Write-Output "Will download $chromeDriverZipLink"

  $chromeDriverZipFileLocation = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver_win32.zip")

  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $chromeDriverZipLink -OutFile $chromeDriverZipFileLocation
  Expand-Archive $chromeDriverZipFileLocation -DestinationPath $(Join-Path $thisScriptRoot $chromeDriverRelativeDir) -Force
  Remove-Item -Path $chromeDriverZipFileLocation -Force
  $chromeDriverFileVersion = (& $chromeDriverFileLocation --version)
  Write-Output "chromedriver updated to version $chromeDriverFileVersion"
}
else {
  Write-Output "chromedriver is actual"
}
```

You can configure relative directory where you need to place `chromedriver` with `$chromeDriverRelativeDir` variable, relatively of script location.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not always but when the versions are not compatible then the answer is YES.

You can see the list of chromedriver versions and the browser versions they support here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/notes.txt

Hope this helps